# PostgreSQL 16 - Seemingly self-contradictory query results

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's a query:

```
SELECT g.id              AS gateway_id,
       ga.id             AS account_id,
FROM public.gateways AS g
         LEFT JOIN public.gateway_accounts AS ga ON (g.id = ga.gateway_id)
where gateway_id = 'a298cf64-af91-4bc4-bd14-126a2d551f93';
```

`public.gateways` has three rows in it, one with the specified ID (`a298cf64-af91-4bc4-bd14-126a2d551f93`), but `public.gateway_accounts` does not have any rows that join on the specified condition for that specific row in `public.gateways`.

**Notice** that the `where` clause tries to refer to the aliased column in the select statement (`g.id`), NOT the column in `public.gateway_accounts`.

I would **expect** this query to return one row with a NULL `account_id` , but **instead** it returns no rows!

If the `where` clause is inverted (`!=`), then the other two rows from `public.gateways` are returned, as expected.
If the `where` clause is removed entirely, it returns the entire `public.gateways` table with the expected NULL `account_id` for that one row.

The three result sets do not correlate with each other the way you would expect them to - the first two do not, when combined, form the third result set.

Why is the database seemingly contradicting itself?

Here's the DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE gateways
(
    id             uuid    DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT gateways_pk
            PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE gateway_accounts
(
    id             uuid    DEFAULT gen_random_uuid() NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT gateway_accounts_pk
            PRIMARY KEY,
    gateway_id     uuid                              NOT NULL
);
-- yes, there is no foreign key
```

Comment: When you do `LEFT JOIN`  but then add filtering based on fields from the "RIGHT" table, you effectively turn it into `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: I.e. move the gateway_id condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: @PM77-1 Your comment helped me figure it out. It's referencing gateway_id from the second table instead of referencing the aliased column. This seems like a bug to me

Comment: `where gateway_id = ...` -- That silently converts the outer join into an inner join. Place the predicate in the `ON` clause instead.

Comment: @bwg325 "...This seems like a bug to me..." -- No. According to the SQL Standard the newly created column is not in the scope of the WHERE clause. It can be in the scope of the ORDER BY clause, however.

Comment: @TheImpaler well, the SQL standard costs money, afaik. I didn't know that. Weird that that would be not in the scope of `where`, but in the scope of `order by`

Comment: "the SQL standard costs money" -- Yes, unfortunately. You can still find the historic, but quite useful, [SQL-92 Standard](https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), though. It does include the main concepts and theory in it. A bit dry, but full of gold dust.

Answer (score 0):

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2055998/pm-77-1) left a comment on the question which helped me figure it out.
See the `gateway_id` in the `where` clause? PostgreSQL thinks it refers to the column in the `public.gateway_accounts`, not the aliased column in the select statement.

I think that's not the desired behaviour for most people...

Comment: Your conclusion is correct and the proposed duplicate is incorrect. That being said, if you search "SQL order of operations" you'll find out why. The select clause is processed after joins.